# Primes in residue classes

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-progression, prime-number-theorem, quadratic-residues

For which sets of residue classes are there easy elementary proofs that there are infinitely many primes in them, which don’t require the machinery of proofs of Dirichlet’s theorem?

Example: it’s simple to prove there are infinitely many primes ending in a digit that is either 3 or 7, because if there were finitely many you could multiply them all together, add a small constant, consider the prime factors of that, and get a contradiction. But what about if you just wanted to show there were infinitely many primes ending in 3, not “3 or 7”? When is that kind of thing relatively easy?

Comment: See [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf)

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec12.pdf

Comment: Thanks very much! Those papers confirm my suspicions.